# How to get data from BigQuery in React.js app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-bigquery

### What I want to do and the problem

I want to access a table in the BigQuery, but got error like

```sh
TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function
    at GoogleAuth.getClient (googleauth.js:497)
    at GoogleAuth.authorizeRequest (googleauth.js:530)
    at BigQuery.makeAuthenticatedRequest (util.js:374)
    at BigQuery.request_ (service.js:129)
    at BigQuery.request (service.js:140)
    at BigQuery.createJob (bigquery.js:942)
    at BigQuery.wrapper (index.js:42)
    at BigQuery.createQueryJob (bigquery.js:862)
    at BigQuery.wrapper (index.js:42)
    at BigQuery.query (bigquery.js:1264)
    at index.js:69
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at BigQuery.wrapper (index.js:54)
    at Signup.handleClick (Signup.js:52)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:336)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:385)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:440)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:454)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:584)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:609)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:713)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:722)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:694)
    at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:739)
    at runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:880)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:5803)
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:24401)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:1415)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:5894)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6010)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5914)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:697)
    at runWithPriority$2 (react-dom.development.js:12149)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:24417)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:1438)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5881)
```

### My Codes

First, I want to check the code with simple code. There is a button and when clicked it, the `handleClick` function works. All element for access BigQuery are in this function for now.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import PersonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Person';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';

class Signup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
    const bigquery = new BigQuery({
        projectId: '(PROJECT_ID)',
        keyFilename: '../../credentials/(credential file name).json',
    });

    const query = `
      SELECT *
        FROM \`(PROJECT_ID).paper_list.user_auth_info\`;
        `

    bigquery.query(query)
      .then(data => {
            const rows = data[0];
            rows.forEach(row => alert("Hello"));
          })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container 
        component="main" 
        maxWidth="xs" 
        className={classes.outer}
      >
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
            <PersonIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Sign Up
          </Typography>
          <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
            <Button
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              className={classes.submit}
              onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

The directory structure is like following,

```sh
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── app.yaml
├── credentials    # <- credential file is in this directory
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── Main.js
    ├── components
    │   ├── AddFile.js
    │   ├── Footer.js
    │   ├── Header.js
    │   ├── Inner.js
    │   ├── Login.js
    │   ├── PaperFolder.js
    │   ├── PaperInfo.js
    │   ├── PaperLabels.js
    │   ├── SearchResultTable.js
    │   ├── SideBar.js
    │   ├── Signup.js    # <- the code above
    │   ├── TopLinks.js
    │   └── ToppageMain.js
    ├── images
    │   └── maarten-van-den-heuvel-8EzNkvLQosk-unsplash.jpg
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── serviceWorker.js
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: It kinda looks like you can only run these queries via `node.js` - which is not used in front-end frameworks like React. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries

Comment: https://github.com/tonyxu-io/react-bigquery-app/blob/master/routes/stackoverflow.js This GitHub repository uses BigQuery in React, but I cannot reproduce...

Comment: Yeah the BigQuery usage is all in the express files, which is server-side code. The React code is only front-end stuff, which is all in `react-bigquery-app/client/`. This project is still calling BigQuery apis from the server-side, even though the server is running locally on your computer.

Comment: I understood, thank you.

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher It would be great if you could post your comment as an answer so that the community may benefit from it

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment by Blundering Philosopher, I could understand the problem.

The BigQuery should be accessed from server-side, but the React.js is front-end, this was the problem. I wrote the　API server with Go, and resolved it.